# How do I disable the "are you sure you want to open this file? (source if from internet)" dialog in Windows?

Tags: windows

Well, the problem is I always check the "do not ask again box", but when a file is read-only, I have to go to properies, uncheck read only, apply, uncheck "block", apply and then check read only again. This is sooo annoying, how can I permanently disable these warnings? If I Download something I'm sure I WILL open it. (except if I know it's a virus)

Comment: Could you specify if you are opening the file straight in the browser (which one), or with the file manager? Why is the file read-only? I assume it is an executable?

Comment: with explorer, yes an executable. Even when opening from chrome the dialog comes up. [image](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_18YBLFP2tdA/SMRlMZeiY8I/AAAAAAAAAAM/7yBfG1I91ZI/s400/regular.JPG) MY OS is windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explorer has several zones, and following [setting the internet zone to safe](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e83792/how-to-disable-the-open-file-security-warning-in-windows-8/), you can change your computer's treatment of those downloaded files:

- open Internet Explorer
- open settings by clicking on the gears icon in the top right hand corner
- in the security tab, click on internet zone icon
- choose custom level
- in the Security settings - Internet zone pop-up, search for "Launching applications and unsafe files (not secure)"
- set to "enable"
- choose "yes" in the warning
- choose "ok"

Comment: Ah finally, I can play my games like a normal human now! You might want to post the revelant parts of that page into the answer, because when the link goes down other users won't benefit.

Comment: That link should not go down, as it is a Q&A site itself. I am not sure how ethical it is to just copy their answers, so I will write a summary.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you from the future for posting this as it still solves the issue in this annoying Windows 10. I updated the steps:

WINKEY>(Type and Search)"Internet Options">Security Tab>Internet (Logo)>Custom Level...>(Scroll 3/4 Down) Launching applications and unsafe files (not secure)>ENABLE

Use at your own risk and maybe don't do for less technical users that might annoy you later.